# Invalidate doesn't cause OnDraw

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have problem with my Android app. I've created custom view (http://syedwasihaider.github.io/blog/2015/07/12/XamarinViews/ up to step 2), overriden onDraw and I draw black screen and text "Draw {i}" where `i` is number that increments every time onDraw occurs. I want to call this method 30 times/second (or 60), so I've set up timer that causes Invalidate() every 33 ms.

But Invalidate() doesn't cause onDraw at all! (It's not like its a delay between invalidate and ondraw, ondraw isn't called at all). I've tried to set `SetWillNotDraw(false)`, but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
class DrawCanvas : View
{
    Context mContext;
    public DrawCanvas(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        init(context);
    }
    public DrawCanvas(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        init(context);
    }
    public DrawCanvas(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context ctx)
    {
        mContext = ctx;

        black = new Paint() { Color = Color.Black };
        white = new Paint() { Color = Color.White };

        Timer timer = new Timer(33);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    int i = 0;
    Paint black;
    Paint white;
    private void TestDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, Width, Height, black);
        canvas.DrawText("Draw " + i, 10, 10, white);
        i++;
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        TestDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**How can I either:**

Call onDraw every 33ms

**OR**

Get canvas that is used in onDraw method? (tried to save canvas that comes as parameter in onDraw and use it later, but there was some weird behaviour, so it didn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Call onDraw every 33ms

You could use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to implement this feature.

Every time your `DrawCanvas` execute the `OnDraw` method, you could send a message to `Handler`, when you receive the message in `Handler`, you could call the `DrawCanvas`'s `Invalidate` method, this `Invalidate` method will call `OnDraw` method. It will keep going.

For example :

```
class DrawCanvas : View
{
     MyHandler mHandler;
     ...
     private void init(Context ctx)
     {
         mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
         mContext = ctx;
         black = new Paint() { Color = Color.Black,TextSize=56 };
         white = new Paint() { Color = Color.White, TextSize = 56 };
     }
     ...
     protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
     {
         TestDraw(canvas);
         mHandler.SendEmptyMessageDelayed(1,33);
     }
     ...
     public class MyHandler : Handler
     {
         private DrawCanvas drawCanvas;

         public MyHandler(DrawCanvas drawCanvas)
         {
             this.drawCanvas = drawCanvas;
         }

         public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
         {
             base.HandleMessage(msg);
             drawCanvas.Invalidate();
         }
     }
}
```

Effect :

[image]

Comment: @York, i stuck in an infinite loop,inside handlemessage method,can you help?

Comment: @ChetanMehra, sure, but raise a new question will be better. :)

Comment: Done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505437/stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-in-runonuithread-handler-class-method

Comment: Any reason why put invalidate() in a handler? Thank you!