# How to convert java handler to c#

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

I am working on a project which is in C#, but, its SDK is in Java, I have converted almost all the code in C#, but, I am having some trouble converting the following Java code into C#:

```
private Handler mhanlder;    
protected Handler getHandler() {
    if (mhanlder == null) {
        mhanlder = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                handleStateMessage(msg);
            }
        };
    }
    return mhanlder;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `some trouble` which trouble? What exactly is a problem?

Comment: I want to convert this code in c# and I am unable to do it :(
and its frustrating for me. Help me.

Comment: You should specify why you are unable to convert it. What **exactly** in this code is a problem. Don't ask us just to do it instead of you, it doesn't work this way.

Comment: in java we can make a method in declaration, like this:

mhanlder = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                handleStateMessage(msg);
            }
        };

but in c# we cannot make a method in a declaration. so, what should I do? how can I achieve this? or is there any substitution for this?

Comment: that is called anonymous class. C# does not have them. So you have to declare it as a standalone class

Comment: any examples? any solution links?

Comment: the solution is to write java's anonymous class as a standalone class. I don't think that this solution requires any links

Comment: Can you show me what are you trying to convert here like what exact code is this

Comment: You could refer to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466427/invalidate-doesnt-cause-ondraw/46480952#46480952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @VIadyslav has said,C# does not have anonymous class, so we need declare it as a standalone class.

`MyHandler` class:

```
public class MyHandler : Handler
{
    public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        base.HandleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
   Handler mHandler;
   public Handler getHanlder() {

        if (mHandler == null) {
            mHandler = new MyHandler();
        }
        return mHandler;
    }
```